# Assets and Channel Form Upload

Tags: assets, channel-form

Is there a way to see the files I have selected and to be able to remove them if needed from the upload file button?

I am using

So I selected for this example 2 files and it only says you have "2 files selected" next to the file button.  Is there a way to get those files to display with their names and an x next to them to remove them if needed?

Comment: How long does it normally take to get a support response?